# Como habilitar los CORS en cpanel o whm de una cuenta reseller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cors

Tengo un problema con mi cuenta de reseller en hostgator.

Estoy intentando hacer una api pero no puedo habilitar los CORS

Ya intente en .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

ya intente con php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080/");
```

Y no se como habilitarlos en apache y dudo que se pueda al ser una cuenta hosting como tal.
Tienen alguna otra idea de como evitar los cors.

Saludos.

Comment: La API la estas creando con php puro o utilizas algún framework?

Comment: estoy utilizando laravel. Descubri que no es el servidor es mi cliente porque hice solicitudes dedes postman y ahi si funcionan

Comment: Te cuento lo que me paso y como lo resolví (no soy experto), yo estoy haciendo una API con php puro, al hacer pruebas con postman funcionaba bien, con el cliente (js) me daba el mensaje de CORS. Investigando y haciendo pruebas con la consola del cliente me di cuenta que cuando el cliente detecta que su dominio es diferente al dominio donde se encuentra la API manda una  petición tipo OPTIONS (adicional a la petición que hayas hecho (GET POST, etc) por lo que con un switch capturo la petición y le devuelvo los headers, comenta si crees que te puede servir y lo pongo como respuesta, aquí no da.